# Trigger to update data in another DB

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have the following schema:

Database: test.
    Table: per_login_user, Field: username (PK), password

Database: wavinet.
    Table: login_user, Field: username (PK), password

What I want to do is to create a trigger. Whenever a `password` field on table `per_login_user` in database `test` get updated, the same value will be copied to field `password` in Table `login_user` in database `wavinet`

I have search trough Google and find this solution: http://forums.devshed.com/ms-sql-development-95/use-trigger-to-update-data-in-another-db-149985.html

But, when I run this query:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgPasswordUpdater ON dbo.per_login_user
FOR UPDATE
AS
UPDATE  wavinet.dbo.login_user
SET     password = I.password
FROM    inserted I
INNER JOIN
    deleted D
ON  I.username = D.username
WHERE   wavinet.dbo.login_wavinet.password = D.password
```

the query return error message:

```
Msg 107, Level 16, State 3, Procedure trgPasswordUpdater, Line 4
The column prefix 'wavinet.dbo.login_wavinet' does not match with a table name or alias name used in the query.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You update login_user, but your FROM clause doesn't contain login_user. That's exactly what the error message is saying actually. If you want to update a table, any table, and the UPDATE statement uses a FROM clause, then the table being updated must be present in the FROM clause:

```
UPDATE  wavinet.dbo.login_user 
SET     password = I.password 
FROM    wavinet.dbo.login_user
JOIN inserted I ON wavinet.dbo.login_wavinet.username = I.username
```

I'm not sure what you want to achieve with the JOIN on the DELETED pseudo-table, nor with your strange WHERE clause. You seem to ignore the trivial case of user A and user B both having the same password and when user A changes his password, your code would change user B's password as well...

As for the simple fact of storing password in clear in the database: very bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Honestly, I'm not really understand T-SQL. I just get the sql query from that link and try to modify it. Thanks for the explanation. And of course password is encrypted in programming language side.